# How can I generate plist and ipa together for wireless distribution in new XCode 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ad-hoc-distribution

I have done this numerous times in XCode 5 and generated ipa (along with plist) for Adhoc Distribution for my app. But in the new XCode 6, I am unable to see this option.

In XCode 5, I saw this screen, which let me put my variables.
[image]

In XCode 6, I press "Export" and ask it do the AdHoc Distribution but it never asks me these things the way it asked in XCode 5. It just generates an ipa.

Is there anything wrong that I am doing?

thanks.

Comment: you copy old Plist and change in it manually.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no way, Xcode 6 fixed old bugs, and also added new bugs.
You need to do that manually, create a plist file with this template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
        <key>items</key>
        <array>
                <dict>
                        <key>assets</key>
                        <array>
                                <dict>
                                        <key>kind</key>
                                        <string>software-package</string>
                                        <key>url</key>
                                        <string>[INSERT URL HERE]</string>
                                </dict>
                        </array>
                        <key>metadata</key>
                        <dict>
                                <key>bundle-identifier</key>
                                <string>[INSERT BUNDLE ID HERE]</string>
                                <key>bundle-version</key>
                                <string>[INSERT VERSION HERE]</string>
                                <key>kind</key>
                                <string>software</string>
                                <key>title</key>
                                <string>[INSERT APP TITLE HERE]</string>
                        </dict>
                </dict>
        </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```